# Why can't I print out the contents of my simple multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is the code I copied from a book to practice on.
I want to print out the content of the multidimensional array.

```
int[][] matrix = new int[4][];
matrix[0] = new int[2];
matrix[1] = new int[6];
matrix[2] = new int[4];
matrix[3] = new int[5];

for (int row = 0; row < matrix.Length; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].Length; column++)
        Console.Write(matrix[row][column] + " "); // Each item in the row separated by spaces

    Console.WriteLine(); // Rows separated by lines
}
```

But the result looks like this:

```
0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

I thought it was supposed to print:

```
0, 2
1, 6
2, 4
3, 5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are making an array of specific sizes, you are not entering data in those arrays

Comment: You create an array with 4 "rows". Each row consists of an array of different lengths. For each row you now go through each column and print the *value* at that row and column index. You have never set these values, so they are 0. Why would you expect to see the row index and the length of the row? you do not print those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it is not a multidimensional array but a [jagged one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays#jagged-arrays) (the multidimensional one would be `int[,] matrix = new int[4,2];` though it will have the same amount of elements in each row).

> What am I missing?

For each "row" you are printing elements of the array in the "row", `new int[2]` for example will create array of 2 integers initialized with default value (which is `0` for `int`), so printing it's elements will result in the `0 0` , `new int[6]` is array of 6 integers (all zeroes), etc.

> I thought it was supposed to print:

TBH it is not very clear why you thought that. But the following should give the results similar to expected (i.e. index of current row and length of the array for the row):

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.Length; row++)
{
    Console.Write(row + " ");
    Console.Write(matrix[row].Length);

    Console.WriteLine(); // Rows separated by lines
}
```

Or a bit shorter version with string interpolation:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.Length; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{row} {matrix[row].Length}");
}
```

If the goal is matrix of size 4x2 then you can to use multidimensional array:

```
// creates and initializes multidimensional array 4x2: 
int[,] matrix = {
    {0, 2},
    {1, 6},
    {2, 4},
    {3, 5},
};

// fixed printing: 
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < matrix.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " "); // Each item in the row separated by spaces
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); // Rows separated by lines
}
```

Comment: I assume because of the name `matrix`, that he actually wants an array `int[,] matrix = new int[4,2];`

Comment: @JeanotZubler thank you! Added version for multidimensional array.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I was actually working on a jagged array... not a multidimensional array as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array, that looks like this:

```cs
[[ 0, 2 ],
 [ 1, 6 ],
 [ 2, 4 ],
 [ 3, 5 ]]
```

Then you are going about it the wrong way.
To create a multidimensional array (not a jagged one) you can use the following syntax:

```cs
int[,] matrix = new int[4,2];
```

Now the array exists in the shape as above, but you still need to actually *assign values* to it:

```cs
matrix[0, 0] = 0;
matrix[0, 1] = 2;
matrix[1, 0] = 1;
matrix[1, 1] = 6;
matrix[2, 0] = 2;
// and so on
```

You can then use your current code to print the array.